# when the tableau primary cluster is down how to bring the up failure primary

Tags: tableau-api

am new to tableau administration I have started setup tableau server in our organization so I have a couple of doubts on the disaster recovery and caching, so when the tableau primary cluster is down how to bring the up failure primary!

what are the steps follow to bring up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the manual for the **tabadmin failoverprimary** command and then follow the links to see more detail